# Apk add pdftk unsatisfiable constraints

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, pdftk

Can somebody explain to me why I get a

```
unsatisfiable constraints:
  pdftk (missing):
    required by: world[pdftk]
```

error when running

```
apk update
apk add pdftk
```

in my alpine docker-image, although it seems to be [included](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=pdftk&branch=edge) in alpine?

Best regards

Comment: At the time of writing this, pdftk is available on Alpine 3.8, but not Alpine 3.9 (which is the latest version). I simply reverted to Alpine 3.8 for now to get the desired effect.

Comment: Updated answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66553937/unsatisfiable-constraints-error-when-installing-pdftk-alpine-linux

Answer (score 6):

It seems there is no local cache of alpine repositories inside your docker image.

So, in order to fix this you can do the following:

**1.** Use `--no-cache` flag when you do `apk add` to not use any local cache path:

```
$ docker run -ti alpine:3.7
/ # apk add --no-cache pdftk
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r5)
(2/5) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
(3/5) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r5)
(4/5) Installing libgcj (6.4.0-r5)
(5/5) Installing pdftk (2.02-r1)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r7.trigger
OK: 76 MiB in 16 packages
```

**2.** Update local cache first (`apk update`) and then install necessary packages (`apk add <package>`):

```
$ docker run -ti alpine:3.7
/ # apk update
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.7.0-159-g08fa87dac2 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/main]
v3.7.0-160-g82f356f8c4 [http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.7/community]
OK: 9050 distinct packages available
/ # apk add pdftk
(1/5) Installing libgcc (6.4.0-r5)
(2/5) Installing gmp (6.1.2-r1)
(3/5) Installing libstdc++ (6.4.0-r5)
(4/5) Installing libgcj (6.4.0-r5)
(5/5) Installing pdftk (2.02-r1)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r7.trigger
OK: 76 MiB in 16 packages
```

P.S. Also please remember that `pdftk` package was added to alpine repositories starting from version 3.5. It could be the case you are using `alpine:3.4` as a base docker image.

P.P.S. `pdftk` package [*is not present*](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/10136) from alpine repositories on 3.9.

Comment: sorry, of course i do a apk update before i try to apk add <package>

Comment: What can we do for alpine:3.9? Any suggestions?